# getch() is working without conio.h - how is that possible?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I started using Visual Studio 2010 (c++) to code in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    printf("test");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

this code works, even without adding `conio.h` library and the program is paused right there, however `getch()`; is underlined and it says, that **Error identifier getch(); is undefined**.

How is that possible?

Comment: Only guessing, but perhaps stdio.h pulls in (some parts of) conio.h? Technically, as long as the code is not using C++ features, you can use functions without declaring them (but you should enable warnings to avoid this).

Comment: I opened stdio and stdlib, crtl+f and searched for getch(), but there is only the original getchar()...

Comment: I bet both of those headers contain other includes tho'.

Comment: maybe it is a special function as in printf() which works when compiled with gcc without the stdio.h. even getch() works with gcc without any header

Comment: "*... without adding conio.h library ...*" `conio.h` is **not** a library, but a header file providing (besides other things) prototypes to functions from a library. Libraries aren't used during compilation, but **after** compilation, that is during linkage.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The C language has a concept of "implicit declarations" for functions. If you don't provide a prototype, the compiler will assume the function was declared like:

```
int getch();
```

meaning that it is a function returning int that doesn't specify information about its parameters. Strictly speaking this is not an error, but many compilers will issue a warning if your warning level is set high enough.  This behavior was removed in C99 onward, and you should generally avoid relying on it.

Since the library still provides the `getch()` function, there is no issue resolving its symbol at link time.  As a result, and due to the fact that `getch()` actually does return an `int`, everything works out.